# Hudson -- Dumb slave

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, hudson-plugins, master-slave

I have been playing with Hudson slaves lately, I was wondering what a dumb slave is? and when is it beneficial to use?

An example would be nice. They suggest there are other types of slaves but they then again list none.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "dumb slave" is the basic slave available with Hudson (presumably extensions could add "smart slaves").  As it is, the "dumb slave" actually provides several different methods for starting processes on a given slave machine.  For more information, see here:

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Distributed+builds

Comment: I have been trying to setup a windows slave to a ubuntu linux master. 

I managed to get hudson running as a service, now how can i link a build on linux master to run on the slave, and have it report back to master.

Thanks.

Comment: @garbagecollector, The article I linked has a couple of suggestions for running a Windows slave, either via Java Web Start, or using WMI+DCOM emulation.  At the bottom of the article there are links for troubleshooting tips for Windows slave problems...

Comment: haha you have any useful information on that topic. The guides are horrible.

Comment: Sorry, haven't needed to setup Windows slaves.  Good luck, and make sure you update the guides when you solve it.

Comment: I don't see your problem. You just tie your job to a slave. you will find that option on the bottom of the first section of the jobs configuration slave. If you give two slaves the same label, you can tie the job here to a label and Hudson will choose on which of the both it will execute the job.